# How to find all numbers in a range that end with certain digits

Tags: python

I need to find all numbers in a certain range that end with specific digits.

For example:

1. find all numbers up-to `15` that end with `5`. Result should be `2` because `5` and `15` end with `5`.
2. find all numbers up-to `125` that end with `12`. Result should be also `2` because `12` and `112` end with `12`.

I tried this brute-force code:

```
def findnumber(n, m):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        if i%10**len(str(n)) == n:
            count += 1
    return count

print(findnumber(5,15))
```

But I need to make the code more efficient.

- The legal values are: `1 <= n, m <= 10**9`

Comment: So for the input of `(5,15)` you would like to return 2?
as for 15 and 5?

Comment: This problem seems simple and using a program doesn't sound ideal, I suspect you have a general case and you are simplifying. Telling us that might help us give you a better answer

Comment: There are only 2 numbers between 1 and 15 both inclusive which end with 5. So it should return 2

Comment: @Hilea the problem is simple over a particular range and after that the time complexity is increasing and i need to solve it in log(n) time complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's **efficient** general algorithm:
with simple assumption i.e for example, **n is 5 and m is 26** then we need to check only for **5, 15, 25** which are offset by **10** i.e **offset = 10 ** (total digits of n)**.

Here's code:

```
def count(n, m):
    cnt    = 0
    num    = n
    ln     = len(str(n))
    offset = 10 ** ln
    
    while num <= m:
        cnt += 1
        num += offset

    return cnt


>>> count(5, 14)
1
>>> count(5, 16)
2
>>> count(5, 25)
3
>>> count(5, 125)
13
>>> count(5, 1125)
113
```

which is efficient in terms of operations

Comment: How is it more optimal than O(1)?

Comment: @Oleg I didn't say that it is optimal that O(1)

Comment: @JaswanthkarPandugayala He means that this solution still loops on the numbers, just with a different step. Oleg's solution has exactly 2 operations no matter the sizes of the inputs...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yep it is true Oleg's solution is better than mine now(after editing)

Answer (score 4):

edited as [Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo) suggested using the floordiv operator:

```
def findnumber(n, m):
    s = 10 ** len(str(n))
    c = m // s
    if m % s >= n:
        c += 1
    return c
```

Comment: Nice solution. BTW, `math.floor` is not necessary, it can just be `c = m // 10`

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo, I've edited my answer, think that's more proper and clean way to do it

Comment: What if m is a triple digit number

Comment: @JaswanthkarPandugayala the size of m doesn't matter as long as it's not negative.
It simply counts the number of times 10 fits in `m` and adds 1 if the last digit is larger or equal to `n`

Comment: @Oleg Let us take 125 as m and 25 as n. According to that we find 25 as last digits in 25,125 so the c is 2. But in your solution the c starts at 12.

Comment: @Oleg to support any length of numbers you just need to change the occurrences of `10` in the code to be `10**len(str(n))`

Comment: JaswanthkarPandugayala, thought you meant last digit in your question, changed it to fit the more general case, still O(1).
@Tomerikoo thank for the support ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
def findnumber(n,m):
  count = 0
  
  #so if you find the first number that ends with n then the problem after wards is 
  #simple you just have to jumpe by ten steps, so lets first find the first number that ends in 
  #which is a lot faster than checkign every entry
  
  foundTheFirst = False
  firstNumber = 1
  while(not foundTheFirst):
      #check if firstNumebr ends in n
      if firstNumber % 10 == n:
          foundTheFirst = True
          break
      firstNumber += 1
  

  for i in range(firstNumber,m+1,10):
        count+=1
  return count
print(findnumber(2,20))
```

Comment: You don't need to take another variable as firstNumber since n is the first multiple you can initiate the loop with n also

Answer (score 1):

Its a lot more simple, and can be done without iterating at all,

each 10 numbers in sequence will have one that ends with `m`, for example :

1 2 3 4 **5** 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 14 **15**

```
def findnumber(n, m):
    n_digits = 0
    n_copy = n
    while n_copy != 0:
        n_digits += 1
        n_copy //= 10

    digits = 10 ** n_digits
    count = m // digits
    if m % digits >= n:
        count += 1
    return count

print(findnumber(5, 15))
print(findnumber(35, 1400))

#  2
#  14
```

Comment: but this wouldn't always work take (2,20) for example

Comment: But that returns a float... Did you mean `(m - n) // 10`?

Comment: @Hilea, for me print(findnumber(2,20)) returns 2 , is it wrong ?

Comment: oh that was my bad. I made a mistake my self

Comment: What if m is a triple digit number

Comment: Why it should matter, as long as m > 0 and 0 < n <= 9, it will be fine

Comment: The above code returns `2.5`... Are you running Python 2 by any chance?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes i have update it so it will work also on python 3, thank you

Comment: Now just note that your assumption is not accurate as `n` can be more than 2-digits long

Comment: I think the question was updated, i will update my function